# trying to make private function in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript .. I am trying to make a private function in JS and access it outside .. here is my code

```js
 function Person(name, gender) {
   this.name = name;
   this.gender = gender;

   //the private function
   function aFunction(arg1) {
     alert("anything");
   }

 }

 var person = new Person("bob", "M");


 person._privates['aFunction']();
```

Comment: *"I am trying to make a private function in JS and access it outside"* - So, a *non*-private function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to make a private function in JS and access it outside

First of all, this statement is an [oxymoron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron), since a private function is by definition private to a scope and hence shouldn't be accessible outside.

If you mean that you want to access a method defined inside `Person` outside it then **->** try to make your `Person` class have a `_privates` member as

```
function Person(name, gender){
   this.name = name;
   this.gender = gender;

   this._privates = {}; //new property added to access private functions

   //the private function       
   this._privates.aFunction = function (arg1){
       alert("anything");
   };
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't work

Comment: @memomemo I tested my code before posting here, what error did you got on your system?

Comment: This is bloated code and doesnt explain or solve the problem in a good way.

Comment: @vonGohren what did i miss?

Comment: To declare a privates object and put your code in there doesnt make things private. Have a look at the answere below. Where there actually is a private method, and a privileged function wrapping the private. You could do something like this with your object, but you have not incorporated an actual private method here.

Comment: @vonGohren Did you read my updated answer before posting your comment? I think I did addressed this point.

Comment: I did not, but still your code does not elaborate about the use of a private function and a function that is privileged. So as for a newcommer like this guy, its important to show him the fundamentals and not just a solution.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you want to have a private method accessible to the outside, it's not really private anymore?

But to answere your question to keep the private method you have there: aFunction().

You need to have a privileged method accessing it to be able to have it triggered.

```
 function Person(name, gender) {
   this.name = name;
   this.gender = gender;

   //the private function
   function aFunction(arg1) {
     alert("anything "+arg1);
   }

   this.nonPrivateFunction = function(param) {
     aFunction(param);
   }

 }

 var person = new Person("bob", "M");


 person.nonPrivateFunction("test");
```

Have in mind that this privileged can be overridden by another method, but the method code itself cannot be changed.

To override do like this, but then you will not have access to the private function

```
person.nonPrivateFunction = function() {
   console.log("overridden")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function Person(name, gender){
   this.name = name;
   this.gender = gender;

   //the private function
   this.aFunction = function(arg1){
       alert("anything");
   }       
}

var person = new Person("bob", "M");  

person.aFunction();
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ponipilula/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Some explanation for why the OP's code doesn't work and why yours does could improve your answer.

Comment: and another question please .. this is considered as a private function as it is defined in a class .. right ??

Comment: In what sense is that a private function? It can be accessed by any code that has a reference to `person`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, it not a strict "private" function